# Geometry of $GL_n(F)$ inside $M_n(F)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces

Consider the linear group $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ of all invertible complex matrices which is *dense* subset in the space of all complex matrices of order $n$ i.e. $M_n(\mathbb C)$. I know that the result is always true whenever the underlying field is algebraically closed. I am searching the same sort of relationship  if $\mathbb C$ is replaced by some finite field $F$. Further what can be said about the subset $S\subset M_n(F)$ of all diagonalizable matrices in the same context?

Any intuitive idea about their topologies or a diagram will be a great help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "topology" in the finite field case. In scheme-y terms it's always true that $GL_n$ is Zariski dense in $M_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace $\mathbb{C}$ by a finite field, say, $F$ of $q=p^l$ element of characteristic $p$, then express $GL_n(F)$ by  $GL_n(q)$ or $GL(n,q)$.

The order of the group $GL(n,q)$ is $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^k)=(q^n-1)(q^n-q) \cdots (q^n-q^{n-1})$.

Definitely it has geometry, for example, with $q=2, \ n=3$, we have the general linear group $GL(3,2)$ which has order $(2^3-1)(2^3-2)(2^3-2^{3-1})=168$.

This  $GL(3,2)$ is the automorphism group of [Fano Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane). It has nice geometry.

Next, Consider $GL(2,2)$ which has order $(2^2-1)(2^2-2)=6$. This is isomorphic to symmetric group $S_3$ which has the geometry of rotation of vertices of a equilateral triangle.

Comment: Thats helpful. But I am looking for relative geometry of $GL_n(F)$ and $M_n(F)$.